# Почему нигде не запускается код?

Tags: c++

Пробовалось: DEV CPP, MVS10, BORLAND.

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()  
{
    cout << "\nHELLO\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Пространство имен не указано, надо:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "\nHELLO\n";
}
```

Comment: Код почему-то не форматируется(

Comment: @IonRod Нужно добавить по четыре пробела (табуляцию) перед каждой строкой в редакторе, чтобы код отформатировался. Или выделить его мышью и нажать на кнопку 101010.

Comment: Я нажимал на 101010 много раз не прокатило(. Буду табами)

Comment: Хочу прокоментировать код ниже. Явное указание не всегда удобно, а человек только начинает изучать с++. STD в ближайшее время ему хватит с запасом, а так надо разбираться с с выбором пространства имен + человек может подумать, что писать можно только так. Соответственно код разрастется ужаасно).

Comment: Хуже будет, если человек подумает, что всегда нужно писать как в вашем примере.
Я всегда стараюсь явно указывать namespace. Если у него уж очень длинное название, то можно сделать алиас (например namespace fs = boost::filesystem;) и далее испольовать его. Явное укаание namespace-а улучшает читаемость кода. В header-ах вообще использовать using namespace не стоит никогда.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что лучше писать полностью - становится более ясно что и как происходит. И в случае чего есть функция поиск+автозамена.

С другой стороны, `using namespace` в cpp-файлах не так уж страшно, но обычно начинающие к этому относятся как к некоей магической фразе, которая все чинит, хотя это не так =)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "HELLO" << std::endl;
}
```